# Read the file line-by-line and use the split() function to break the line into a list of integers using python

Tags: python, list, split, integer

I have read the file line by line but now do not know how to make the lines into a list of integers.

This is what I have:

def adjMatrixFromFile(file):

```
Our_numbers = []
file = open(file, 'r')
n =0
while True: 
    line = file.readlines()
    if not line:
        break
    for i in line: 
        numbers = i.split(' ')
        Our_numbers.append(numbers) 
new_ourNumbers = []
for d in Our_numbers:
    for k in d:
        result = k.split(' ')
        new_ourNumbers.append(result)    
return new_ourNumbers
```

print(adjMatrixFromFile("file"))

this is the file:

```
''''5 
    0 1 
    1 2  1 2  1 3  1 3  1 4 
    2 3 
    3 0 
    4 0  4 2
```

Comment: Sample input and expected output?

Comment: this is the output to the code so far:

Comment: [['5'], ['\n'], ['0'], ['1'], ['\n'], ['1'], ['2'], [''], ['1'], ['2'], [''], ['1'], ['3'], [''], ['1'], ['3'], [''], ['1'], ['4'], ['\n'], ['2'], ['3'], ['\n'], ['3'], ['0'], ['\n'], ['4'], ['0'], [''], ['4'], ['2'], ['\n'], ['\n']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this "tiny.txt":

```
5 
0 1 
1 2  1 2  1 3  1 3  1 4 
2 3 
3 0 
4 0  4 2
```

and this code:

```
def adjMatrixFromFile(file):
    Our_numbers = []
    file = open(file, 'r')
    line = file.readlines()

    for i in line:
        i=i.replace('\n','') #remove all \n 
        numbers = i.split(' ')
        numbers = filter(None, numbers) #remove '' in the list
        Our_numbers.extend(numbers) #add values from a list to another list

    Our_numbers = [int(i) for i in Our_numbers] #convert all element str -> int
    return Our_numbers

print(adjMatrixFromFile("tiny.txt"))
```

I got this output:

```
[5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2]
```

Comment: sorry should have included the list:

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file looks something like this:

```
1 5 13
-7 8 99
10 0 1
```

Making it a simple list of integers:

```
our_numbers = []
for line in open(filename):
    our_numbers.extend( [ int(num) for num in line.split() ] )
```

You will get a ValueError if an element of a line cannot be parsed as integer.

Making it a matrix like "list of lists":

```
our_numbers = []
for line in open(filename):
    our_numbers.append( [ int(num) for num in line.split() ] )
```